# Php image/file upload no errors - white page

Tags: php, upload

I a attempting to write an upload script but I am getting no errors with error reporting on and just a blank screen, I have checked the script and cannot spot any syntax errors as far as I can see - I know which part is causing the error but not sure why?

It is this first block because if I remove it the form shows:

```
<?php # uploading files woooo


// CHECK IF THE FORM HAS BEEN SUBMITTED:
if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    // CHECK FOR AND UPLOADED FILE:
    if (isset($_FILES['upload'])) {

        // VALIDATE THE TYPE. SHOULD BE JPEG OR PNG.
        $allowed = array ('image/pjpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/JPG', 'image/X_PNG', 'image/PNG', 'image/x-png');
        if (in_array($_FILES['upload']['type'], $allowed)) {

            // MOVE THE FILES OVER
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], "../uploads/{$_FILES['upload']['name']}")){
                echo '<p><em>the file has been uploaded</em></p>';
            } // END OF MOVE.... IF.

        } else { // INAVALID TYPE.
            echo '<p class="error">Please upload a JPEG or PN image.</p>';
        }

    }
}
```

the script continued seems ok...

```
// CHECK FOR AN ERROR:

    if ($_FILES['upload']['error'] > 0) {
        echo '<p class="error">the file could not be uploaded because <strong>';

            // PRINT A MESSAGE BASED UPON THE ERROR

            switch ($_FILES['upload']['error']) {
                case 1:
                    print 'The file exceeds the upload_max filesize setting in php.ini';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    print 'The file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE setting in the html form';
                    break;
                case 3:
                    print 'The file was only partially uploaded';
                    break;
                case 4:
                    print 'No file was uploaded';
                    break;
                case 6:
                    print 'No temp folder was available.';
                    break;
                case 7:
                    print 'Unable to write to the disk.';
                    break;
                case 8:
                    print 'File upload stopped.';
                    break;                      
                default:
                    print 'A system error occured';
                    break;

            } // END OF SWITCH

            print '</strong></p>';

        } // ENF OF ERROR IF

        // DELETE THE FILE IF STILL EXISTS

        if (file_exists ($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']) && is_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'])) {
            unlink ($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);

        } // ENF OF SUBMITTED FORM

    ?> 


<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="info.php">

    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="524288">

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Select a JPEG or PNG image of 512kb or smaller to be uploaded</legend>
        <p><b><input type="file" name="upload"></p>
    </fieldset>

    <div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /></div>


</form>
```

Comment: A closing `)` is missing on the first line of the code. Also, probably you want to check if `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` is set and after that check if it is equal to `POST`.

Comment: *"but I am getting no errors with error reporting on"* - rather hard to believe. As @user3584460 pointed out, that should have thrown a parse error. are you "displaying" them? `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: *"I have checked the script and cannot spot any syntax errors as far as I can see - I know which part is causing the error but not sure why?"* - you're contradicting yourself.

Comment: @user3584460 hm I added in the missing `)` but still nothing

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am using that exact method but just a blank page?

Comment: Might be a silly question but I'll ask it anyways. The extensions, are indeed `.php`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- they are yes, if I take out that first block in my question above it will show the form and show the errors but the actual part for the upload is giving me the problem

Comment: `if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')`   it should be `if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'POST') `  I mean ending parenthesis missing

Comment: @phpcoder You should have some entry in the Apache error_log. I tested the script and when I change it to `if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])) {` and `if (isset($_FILES['upload']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {` it works fine.

Comment: @user3584460 ok brill but now I get this:   Notice: Undefined index: upload in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dashboardr v3.2.3/info.php on line 51

Notice: Undefined index: upload in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dashboardr v3.2.3/info.php on line 90